# Continue program execution after showAndWait javafx

Tags: javafx

Hello I have a procedure who load a stage like this :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(ConstantsUI.CHEMIN_VIEW+
                ConstantsUI.ECRAN_CAISSE_FERMEE));
        AnchorPane ecran = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(ecran);

        MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().setScene(scene);

        genericController = loader.getController();
        genericController.setStage(MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage());

        // on garde la fenêtre en premier plan
        MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().setMaximized(true);
        MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().show();
        MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().showAndWait();
        System.out.println("toto");
```

And I have an button with this code :

```
@FXML
public void clickButton() {
    System.out.println("------here-----");
    stage.close();
}
```

My problem is, that after I clicked on my button, the message "toto" is not visible. Why ?

Thanks.

Comment: `stage.close` is that a refference to a field, or a call to a method?

Comment: On my class with a fonction clickButton (genericController), I have a variable "stage" who reference the stage on my MainApp. I initialize like this : "genericController.setStage(MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage());"

Comment: Sorry it's "stage.close();"

Comment: Why do you call `show()` and `showAndWait()` on the same `Stage`? BTW: to provide additional information useful to all users or fix a typo in the question, please [edit] it.

Comment: Because if i remove the line "MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().show();", the window is not visible.

Comment: If the window is not visible by calling `showAndWait()` without calling `show()`, then something else is wrong in your code (i.e. in code you haven't posted). Create (from scratch) a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem and [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `showAndWait` is not allowed for the primary stage.

[From the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--)

> **Throws:**
>           [...]
>           `IllegalStateException` - if this method is called on the primary stage.

You could instead use a `onHidden` event handler:

```
MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().setOnHidden(evt -> {
    System.out.println("toto");
});
MainApp.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().show();
```

Alternatively if you want to run the code after the last window of the application has been closed (asumming you didn't use [`Platform.setExplicitExit(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-)), you could override [`Application.stop()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--):

```
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("toto");
}
```